# JavaFx TreeView : how to loop on every item whatever root or child

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, treeview

I'd like to loop on all items of a TreeView tv, whatever the node is parent or child. So let's say my tv has 2 roots : "animal" and "nature" with respectively children. "animal" -> "rabbit","dog","cat" and "nature"->"mountain", "sea", "forest". So I just want to loop on this tv and print :

```
animal
rabbit
dog
cat
nature
mountain
sea
forest
```

Is there any short way to do it ?

Bonus question : Actually my goal is to clearselection for some of the items (example: "cat" and "sea") if they were previously selected so it would be great if I could use the code for printing the tree items in order to apply on it something like

```
tv.getSelectionModel().clearSelection(i);
```

where "i" could be the index of the TreeItem of "cat" or "sea".

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Create a small sample program that shows what you got going on.

Comment: Sounds like you want a depth-first search (DFS) algorithm. You should be able to find a tutorial for that.